# Postfix can receive but can't send emails

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

Can someone please help, I setup Postfix and can receive, but can't send email from my server, when I use Gmail smtp i can send emails as Gmail user but that is not what I want.

Here is my Mail Queue:

[image]

Checked if port is open by some website:

[image]

Telnet from my local network on port 25 say:

```
gam.gamblershome.info EMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

I am not an expert, if someone can help me I will be more than grateful.

Comment: Quick update

FROM MY SERVER HOSTED ON HOSTGATOR:


root@gam.gamblershome.org [~]# telnet smtp.gmail.com

Trying 74.125.25.109...

telnet: connect to address 74.125.25.109: Connection refused

Trying 74.125.25.108...

telnet: connect to address 74.125.25.108: Connection refused

Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c03::6c...

telnet: connect to address 2607:f8b0:400e:c03::6c: Network is unreachable



AND FROM MY HOME SERVER: 

hadis@gam:~$ telnet smtp.gmail.com

Trying 173.194.67.108...

Comment: You have to specify the port when telnetting. In this case you need to tell it to connect via port 25 (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Your own port 25 being open has nothing to do with outgoing email.

If you're getting connection timeouts to big email providers like Google and Hotmail I would suggest one of three things is happening:

- Your ISP blocks outbound port 25. This is increasingly popular on home ISPs to stop spam. They will force you to use their central mailserver.
- You are inadvertently blocking outbound port 25. This would be something you've actively done. Check your ufw/iptables rules for spurious deny rules.
- The remote services are blocking you.

But double check the real log with `sudo less /var/log/mail.log` and make sure you're not missing any obvious issues your pretty logs above aren't showing.

You can also debug more simple network issues with simple tools:

```
ping mx1.hotmail.com
```

If ping fails, there's a serious network-level issue. You managed to look it up in the first place so DNS should be fine but if you can't ping it that might suggest you're being blocked completely.

```
telnet mx1.hotmail.com 25
```

That should open up a raw connection to the remote mailserver. If that doesn't work, you know it's not postfix that's tripping over.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i can ping mx1.hotmail.com but when telnet it just conecting...

and here is part of log file

elivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Feb 25 06:49:14 gam postfix/qmgr[12062]: 5FB199A1217: removed
Feb 25 06:51:13 gam postfix/anvil[14486]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:93.174.93.51) at Feb 25 06:47:53
Feb 25 06:51:13 gam postfix/anvil[14486]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:93.174.93.51) at Feb 25 06:47:53
Feb 25 06:51:13 gam postfix/anvil[14486]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Feb 25 06:47:53
Feb 25 07:00:01 gam postfix/pickup[14010

Comment: IS THIS MEAN THAT ISP blocks outbound port 25?

Comment: I can't work out what that log is saying without its formatting. Edit your question to add some of it (and use the code formatting) and I'll take a look.

Comment: I can't answer to my own quetion and can't use code formating.

Just let me know if I telnet mx1.hotmail.com 25 from any pc at my home network and it won't connect, is that mean that ISP blocks outbound port 25?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> If I telnet mx1.hotmail.com 25 from any pc at my home network and it
>   won't connect, is that mean that ISP blocks outbound port 25?

Yes, your ISP is blocking port 25 outbound.

You can try contacting your ISP to request unblocking port 25; some will, some won't. And many times when they do unblock it, it will get blocked again at some point as they re-provision network services.

Your other option is to find an SMTP relay service that will allow the use of alternate ports, like the 465 and 587 submission ports. Most of these services now charge a fee, though there are still a few free ones out there (I use reachmail.net and was able to get a free relay set up with them). Google searching and researching their service offering is your best plan for this option.

The one downside of using alternate ports is speed: delivery takes much longer to complete.
The upside of using an SMTP relay is that you will avoid the blacklisting problems associated with your ISP - I see that your domain is on the Zen and Spamhaus blacklists because of your ISP's IP for your connection.